# Task Scheduler with Anaconda Python

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to use the Windows Task Scheduler to run a Python file but it seems to fail on anything more complex than command to save to a text file.

I have a python file that I'm able to run from the command prompt. When I move it to be scheduled, it fails. I've stripped back a file to only set a variable and save that value and other messages out to a text file and it runs. But as soon as I add something as simple as simple as import pandas as pd, it fails.

This is the first time I've tried this with this particular laptop. So maybe there's a configuration missing?

Removed all code except:

```
with open('SES Automation Status.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('\n Imported Packages')
```

This works. Setting variables and printing the value out to the same file will also work. Anything more complex fails and it looks like it fails on the validation prior to running as if I put an import package instruction prior to one of the write to files that was running before, the whole thing fails.

Have tried running Task Scheduler in Admin and also have run with highest privleges selected. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvVwB.png). Doesn't work.

If tried invoking both the Anaconda prompt python location and another instance of python on the system in task scheduler and neither work. 0x2331 is the error code I receive on the non-Anaconda instance.

Comment: What does "fail" mean **exactly?**

Comment: Task completes but all commands after any line stop running. Last Run Result = (0x1).